# Linq build query dynamically with no concrete Type

Tags: c#, linq

Actually I'm deploying a generic search control, this because I have many Entities that need to be "searcherd"

**My aproach:** An interfase ISearshable

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    object SearchType { get; }
    string SearchField { get; set; }
    string SearchField2 { get; set; }
    string DisplayField { get; set; }
    decimal SelectedKey { get; set; }
}
```

The clases must implement this interfase something like this:

```
public partial class PeopleInfoBasica : ISearchable
{
    public string SearchField
    {
        get { return StrSearchKey; }
    }
    public string SearchField2
    {
        get { return StrSearchKeyPhoneDir; }
    }
    public string DisplayField
    {
        get { return StrNombreUsuario; }
    }
    public decimal SelectedKey
    {
        get { return NumIdContrato; }
    }
    public object SearchType
    {
        get { return new PeopleInfoBasica(); }
    }
}
```

And many other could implement it.Now my generic object must proccess the filters something like this:

```
    private Task PrimerFiltro(string primerfiltro)
    {
        MiContext db = Credentials.Db;
        //  Se aplica el primer filtro a la lista
        var itemsQ = (from i in db.**Here I Need to Specify dynamically the type**
                      where i.SearchField.Contains(primerfiltro)
                      select i
                      ).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayField);

        filteredList = itemsQ.ToList();
        ListaBase = filteredList;
    }
```

**My question is:** There is a way to dynamically specify the Type to linq? 
maybe another aproach?

`var itemsQ = (from i in db.`**Here I Need to Specify dynamically the type**
                      `where i.SearchField.Contains(primerfiltro)
                      select i
                      ).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayField);`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on what you want to do? Why must you implement this interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses SQL to query the DB. I've taken the liberty of dropping the interface to make the answer shorter.

First, the model class:

```
[SearchField("StrSearchKey")]
public partial class PeopleInfoBasica
{
    public string StrSearchKey { get; set; } //The property to search on. Created by EF or code-first
...
```

}

Note the new Attribute with the search field in it:

```
public class SearchFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SearchFieldAttribute(string searchField)
    {
        SearchField = searchField;
    }

    public string SearchField { get; private set; }
}
```

To get the searchField, use:

```
var attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SearchFieldAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as SearchFieldAttribute;
var searchField = attribute.SearchField;
```

Please add safety checks before using above.

Combining the above, you should now be able to query using:

```
_db.Set(yourType).SqlQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.{0} WHERE {1} LIKE '%{2}%'", tableName, searchField, primerfiltro))
```

The table name can be found from the class name or EF. Depending on whether you use CodeFirst, have pluralization, etc.

Please note that I first tried a solution with building an Expression tree, but it has the same issue of not being able to use OfType().

I still think the best solution is to try to make the method where you search generic, or to simply write your queries for each class. It may be more code, but it is less prone to breaking.

Above code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so please beware.

Comment: HI. tks for your help. What library must use to get Access to this method ?

Comment: Actually I'm using EF 6.1 and can't find ``Set`` Method. I'd like your solution but can´t find the way to implement it. Please Could you explain it a Little more detailed. TKS

Comment: Hmm. I don't quite understand why you can't see that. It has been there since 5.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: It is extrange since i upgrade from EF 5.0 to 6.1 and my projects has a reference to ``System.Data`` instead of ``System.Data.Entity`` I'm going search more about it. Again tks.

Comment: What is the Type of your Credentials.Db? (Where does MiContext inherit from?)

Comment: It inherits from System.Data.Entity.DbContext. But the other Project was referencing System.I removed Sytem.Data and testing at this time.

Comment: I Have a problem with your sugested implementation, It throws an exception **"ISearchable' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.**"

Comment: Ah. It would appear that it is not possible to 'rename' a field such as this, as the Database doesn't know that SearchField maps to StrSearchKey. You could try your hand at building the Expression dynamically.

Comment: I have written a new answer using SQL.

Comment: Thats was te exat way was taken for me. Tks to your first answer. Allready marked as the answer. Again tks for your interest in help me

Answer (score 2):

Make your method generic accepting a type parameter `T` which implements your `ISearchable` interface, and add a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` that can be used by the [`Queryable.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
private Task PrimerFiltro<T>(string primerfiltro, Expression<Func<T,bool>> filterExpression) where T: ISearchable
{
    var db = Credentials.Db;

    var set = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();

    var filteredList = set.Where(filterExpression)
                          .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayField)
                          .ToList();

    ListaBase = filteredList;
}
```

Notice that I'm using the [`CreateObjectSet()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to acquire the entity set corresponding to type `T` dynamically.

Comment: Tks for your help.. but how can I do to run this If I Haven't the type. The only reference to the type is an Object.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez since your objects implement a common interface, I believe [Troels Larsen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24618800/643085) will serve you better.